# C# Count files in folder by minute

Tags: c#

I would like to count the number of XML files created per minute in a directory.

```
8:00am - 40

8:01am - 10

8:02am - 20
```

So in the code I can say show all times that have files > 15 and see something like this.

```
8:00am - 40

8:02am - 20
```

So far:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(@"C:\XML\*.XML");
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;
\\Do the by minute thing
```

Comment: FileSystemWatcher => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: I added "So far:" but only to add a divider between the output and the code. Let us know if that's not what you meant with that snippet

Answer (score 1):

`GetFiles()` will return an array of `FileInfo` which has a property called [`CreationTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can use to get day/hour/minute... and then use Linq's `GroupBy` to group it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var count = dir.GetFiles().Count(x=> x.CreationTime > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to enumerate and split the files into separate files each into each time bucket, first.

```
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("asd");
    var files = dir.EnumerateFiles();
    var count = files.Where(x=> x.CreationTimeUtc.TimeOfDay == TimeSpan.Parse("8:00")).Count();
```

You just need to change the `TimeSpan.Parse("")` to match the buckets you want to use, likely via ranges, then count at the end.